# Add attribute to Rails 5 model, which not exists in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have tables - `users` and `articles`. It is one to many relation or user can have many articles. What I want is to select all users from `users` table with `LIMIT 40`, but include count all articles for each user - add property for each user `count_articles`. I am trying in this way:

```
def self.get_users(limit, offset)
  users = []
  order('created_at').limit(limit).offset(offset).each do |user|
    user.attributes[:count_articles] = user.articles.count
    users << user
    byebug
  end
  users
end
```

, but I am getting users without this attribute. If I use byebug and type in the 
 console - `user.count_articles`, I can see the result of `count_articles` for current user, but if I type only `user`, I see all the attributes without `count_articles`.

Comment: The `ActiveRecord::Base#inspect` method in Rails 5.0 only includes column names. Rails 5.1 includes virtual attribute names.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with:

```
User.joins(:articles)
    .select('users.id, users.name, COUNT(articles.id) AS count_articles')
    .group('users.id')
    .limit(40)
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer.  This returns me no user, if there is no article for him. I fixed with left join like this `joins("LEFT JOIN articles ON users.id = articles.user_id").select()`. I know that the way that works is the best way :), but I thought that there is a better Rails way.

Comment: `left_joins` maybe? `User.left_joins(:articles).select('users.id, users.name, COUNT(articles.id) AS count_articles').group('users.id')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing s.th. similar with a sub-select. So no join is required.

Try putting this into your User Model:

```
def self.get_users(limit=40, offset=0)
  order(:created_at)
  .limit(limit)
  .offset(offset)
  .select('users.*, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM articles WHERE articles.id = users.id) articles_count')
end
```

The resulting User instances in the returned Array will then have the attribute "articles_count".